# How to convert Unreal skyboxes to Unity skyboxes?

Tags: unity, unreal, skybox

I have purchased some **Unreal** skyboxes in the past. Now, I want to use these Unreal skyboxes in **Unity** to develop mobile apps.

Is there an easy way to convert **Unreal** skyboxes to **Unity** skyboxes ?

---

I am not sure which formats the skyboxes have.

Here is the link to the Unreal asset inside the official Unreal marketplace website:  https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/space-skybox-collection-bundle

Comment: The license you purchased the items under expressly forbids this question.

Comment: Can you identify the specific source of these skyboxes so we can verify whether the licence permits this use, as Strom points out, and so we can get details on the format they use?

Comment: @DMGregory, I purchased the assets from the official "Unreal Engine Marketplace" (from https://www.unrealengine.com/).  So, can I convert those Unreal skyboxes to Unity skyboxes to use them inside Unity game engine ? If not, would you please send me the link to the Unreal license agreement that disallows me to do so ? Thanks.

Comment: @Strom, I bought those assets from the official "Unreal Engine Marketplace" (from unrealengine.com) about 2 years ago. I still have the receipt. But, I have not logon  Unreal for 2 years. Now after I logon Unreal, I forget how to access those assets that I bought. Can you please tell me how to view the old assets that I already bought inside Unreal ? Thanks.

Comment: [Based on the FAQ answer here](https://marketplacehelp.epicgames.com/s/article/Can-I-use-these-products-in-other-gaming-engines-like-Source-or-Unity?language=en_US), it depends on whether the specific skyboxes you're trying to use were made by Epic themselves, and if not, whether the creator added any specific licensing terms into their pack. Remember that I've also asked you to clarify what format the skyboxes are in ("Unreal" is not a skybox format), as this is relevant to the process to import them or adapt them for Unity.

Comment: @DMGregory, Sorry I am not sure which format it is. Can you tell what format it is from looking at the link to the asset ? Here is the link to the asset inside Unreal: https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/en-US/product/space-skybox-collection-bundle

Comment: The asset you link has a Q&A section where someone asked two years ago whether they could use them in Unity, and the author replied that the assets are not available for Unity. From the description, it sounds like these skyboxes are not simply images, but Unreal materials that include shader logic. You would need to manually implement a comparable shader in Unity — there is no automatic converter you can use. We will not be able to coach you in how to implement such a shader without buying the assets to reverse engineer them, so this is a skill you'll need to pick up for yourself.

Comment: @DMGregory, Thank you so much for your valuable input. I will see what I can do.

Comment: surely when you download the asset you will see what the file format is.

Comment: Given that FAQ, I stand corrected.  The  FAQ directly contradicts the license agreement agreed to but...